# Account Name (multi value; Term Set is "Customers") wont show up in "Search Options"

Tags: search, managed-metadata, term-store

I did a crawl after setting up the custom property in "Manage User properties" (this property a multi value and term set is customers). I should be able to get a drop down or picker on this field in "Search Options" in people search. But is not there. It's just blank. (however, if i input a searchable keyword to search; it does search). But i need this NOT to be  input box. It should be picker based on the Term Set that's being associated during custom field setup. (as I understood it).

```
<Properties>
<Property Name="CustomerAccount" ManagedName="CustomerAccount" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:CustomerAccount"/>
</Properties>
```

Here is a sample 
[image]

Comment: You need to clean up this question a bit to get answers. It is quite confusing what you want to achieve. Try and attach a picture or two to make it more clear. Eg. Is it people search or normal?

Comment: Yes sir. I am talking about People Search. and "Search Option" in it. I was under the impression that it "CustomerAccount" will look like a managed metadata field when it's associated with a manage term set. http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-79-57-metablogapi/5001.clip_5F00_image033_5F00_37821754.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this works quite as you expect. I have never seen other than just plain anilla text boxes in people search options...

Do you have a reference that claims this is how it works?

I agree it would make sense, but unfortunately taxonomies are not integrated into every part of the platform (yet)

EDIT:
I researched adding taxonomy fields to the search options dialogue, and found [this](http://kgraeme.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/sharepoint-user-profile-custom-properties-keyword-search-problem/) article, that describes pretty much what you try to do. He fails however, and even though he had PSS (MS support) on the case did not come up with a working solution.

Two other people found similar issues and chose different workarounds. Check [here](http://www.sharepointsteve.com/2010/10/making-custom-user-profile-properties-searchable-in-sharepoint-2010/) and [here](http://blog.petergerritsen.nl/2010/10/12/people-search-use-a-custom-ranking-model-to-search-in-added-profile-properties/).

So, probably not what you want to hear.

One thing i noticed was that there is already are a taxonomy field in the search options OOB (that is if you enabled enterprise keywords or mapped Skills to a taxonomy as I have):

```
<Property Name="PersonKeywords" ManagedName="PersonKeywords" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:SPS-PersonKeywords">      
    <EffectiveProperty Name="Responsibility" ManagedName="Responsibility" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:SPS-Responsibility"/>      
    <EffectiveProperty Name="Skills" ManagedName="Skills" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:SPS-Skills"/>      
    <EffectiveProperty Name="Interests" ManagedName="Interests" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:SPS-Interests"/>   
</Property>
```

And these definately are not showing any taxonomy tree view, they just do what the other fields in search options do: prefix the search word with `<managedprop>:<searchterm>` so i guess this is what you get in this release.:

```
(Responsibility:"test" OR Skills:"test" OR Interests:"test")
```

Comment: When setting up a multi value custom field in SP 2007 for user profile they gave us an option to populate a choice list for end user to pick from. and I heard it's been replaced by the term store (or term sets). In sp 2007 those choices were passed to "Search options" for end user to limit the searches within picked items. Should I call Microsoft or open a ticket?

Comment: I agree on the first part: choice fields have been replaced by term sets. But i am not sure this means you get a treeview control or similar in people searc options unfortunately. What did you get in people search options in SP2007? i have never seen anything but simple text boxes in these fields...

Comment: This http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sharepoint2010customization/thread/aa28f6e8-ebbb-4107-bd39-73731ba2a650 sound like it but I have no idea how to create custom button with term store hierarchy with XSL

Comment: That link does not work for me

Comment: Fixed the link (it had quotes around it)

Comment: @Kit: Thanks for fixing the link. @Anders: I finally had my boss going to the old box (sp2007) and I went through the screen where the choice fields were populated for end user to select (in Search Options box). So basically the custom fields and choices where passed on to the "search Options".

Comment: @SPEveryone: I am still waiting for a solution to this.

Comment: Yeah, i was hoping to have had time to look at it today but i have been busy all day. Will lookt at it in an hour or so

Comment: @Hi: anything new on this?

Comment: @luA didnt you see i updated my answer a week ago?